# Excel/Sheets DATEVALUE("2015-08-11") equivalent in R

Tags: r

In Excel or Google Sheets I can convert a date to the number of days since January 1, 1900 using the [DATEVALUE("2015-08-11")](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) Function.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: You can try `as.numeric(as.Date('2015-08-11', origin='1900-01-01'))`

Comment: This gives me 16658, where as spreadsheets give me 42227

Comment: ....which is the same as `as.numeric(as.Date('2015-08-11'))` ? Looks like it's defaulting to 1970 and ignoring the origin parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks akrun for giving me a place to start as an R noob.

By default R converts date from 1970-01-01, so I needed to add the days between 1900-01-01 and 1970-01-01.  Then, to match excel exactly, I need to add two:
+1 for the [leap year bug/feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug), and +1 because the day 1970-01-01 didn't get counted anywhere yet.

```
#get number of days since 1970-01-01
a = as.numeric(as.Date('2015-08-11')) 

# get number of day from 1970 to 1900. This will be negative, so subtract it later
b = as.numeric(as.Date('1900-01-01'))

#numeric representation matching Excel and Sheets:
c = a - b + 2
```

Maybe there's a more elegant solution out there?